# Compare dates in pl/sql using Toad?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I rarely use Oracle, and I'm having trouble comparing date columns.

I have a `pl/sql` table `Transactions` with two columns: TransDate of data_type *Date* and Amount of data_type *Number*.

Querying `Transactions` with Toad will display this:

```
TransDate                  Amount
6/25/2017 12:45:00 AM      5000
6/25/2017 12:48:00 AM      8000
6/25/2017 01:25:00 AM      10000
6/25/2017 11:50:00 AM      9000
6/25/2017 11:52:00 PM      9000
6/26/2017 00:12:00 AM      2000
```

How can I return all rows between `6/25/2017 12:40:00 AM` and `6/25/2017 12:50:00 AM`? Or rows between `6/25/2017 11:50:00 PM` and `6/26/2017 00:20:00 AM`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you;

```
select * from Transactions where TransDate > to_date('6/25/2017 00:20:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TransDate < to_date('6/25/2017 23:50:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying >= and <=, you can also simplify your statement by using the BETWEEN operator.

```
SELECT * FROM  [table] 
WHERE [time] BETWEEN '2017-06-25 23:50:00' AND '2017-06-25 00:20:00'
```